# Multiple "instances" of the same partial template in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have an AngularJS app that displays several plots. Each plot has a set of date controls to allow the user to change the start and end dates of the plotted data range. The date controls are loaded as a partial template in a uib-popover.

I've been using separate partial templates for each plot. I include the template in the page between `<script type="text/ng-template"></script>` tags, and load it using `<button uib-popover-template="foo">Controls</button>`.

This works fine, but having separate templates for each plot seems very repetitive, especially since I have several plots on the page. I tried creating a single template, setting the name of the plot for that "instance" of the template using `ng-init`, and hoping that would allow me to dynamically load the plot values into the template for that particular plot. Something along the lines of this:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.plots = {
    "goodPlot": {
      "start": "1/1/2018",
      "end": "1/1/2019"
    },
    "betterPlot": {
      "start": "5/5/2018",
      "end": "3/10/2019"
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <h4>First Plot</h4>
  <div ng-init="thisPlot = plots.goodPlot" ng-include="'plotControls.tmpl'"></div>
  <hr/>
  <h4>Second Plot</h4>
  <div ng-init="thisPlot = plots.betterPlot" ng-include="'plotControls.tmpl'"></div>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="plotControls.tmpl">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label">Start Date</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="thisPlot['start']">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label">End Date</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="thisPlot['end']">
    </div>
  </script>
</div>
```

But as you can see, the start/end dates for both plots are the same. I understand why this is -- they're both binding to the same variables. But I can't figure out a solution to achieve the desired result.

Basically, I'm looking to create multiple "instances" of the same template, but with different variable values to be set before the `ng-include`.

Can anyone offer any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a component to instantiate the template:

```
app.component("myPlotControls", {
    bindings: { "plot", "<" },
    templateUrl: "plotControls.tmpl",
})
```

Usage:

```
<my-plot-controls plot="plots.goodPlot"></my-plot-controls>

<my-plot-controls plot="plots.betterPlot"></my-plot-controls>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="plotControls.tmpl">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label">Start Date</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="$ctrl.plot['start']">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label">End Date</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="$ctrl.plot['end']">
    </div>
  </script>
```

Components create an isolate scope so that multiple instantiations of the same template will not conflict in the parent scope.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Creating Custom Components](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component)